# Force.com IDE Winter 16 test no longer shows which lines of code were not executed

Tags: unit-test, force.com-ide

When I setup and run a test in Winter 16, the results no longer show me which lines of code didn't execute. That information was invaluable when trying to increase code coverage! How can I get this information again?

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting "Run All" then look at the code coverage and in that bottom right section where you have all your classes

[image]

click on the individual page and you should be able to see the code coverage

Comment: I had this issue recently and can confirm that "Run All" fixed it.

Comment: I continually have trouble with the developer console in Chrome & Firefox & IE. It *very often* but not always comes up with empty drop-down menus and I can't do anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've noted the same issue in the eclipse IDE after updating to the Winter '16 plugin. The only work around is to run review test result in developer console as mentioned above. The previous eclipse plugin was so much more convenient, you could see the lines that were not covered, double click on them and go directly to the source.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found viewing the class test in setup and running the test there will make code coverage resume. useful if you don't have time to run all.